# How to change shape of FAB(Floating action button) as rectangle and adding text too on android?

Tags: android

**[Floating button with icon and text]**

[image]

I am trying to do like this but don't know how to apply to fab

```
    <selector xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <ripple android:color="@color/white" tools:ignore="NewApi">
                <item>
                    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                        <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
                        <corners
                            android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
                            android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
                            android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
                            android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
                    </shape>
                </item>

        </ripple>
    </item>
```

Comment: http://www.android4devs.com/2015/03/how-to-make-floating-action-button-fab.html

Comment: @VishvaDave I tried this one but on fab it is not applying, as it work on simple Button.

Comment: Yes it is not possible on fab may be. so this link gives exact same output but on button

Comment: thanks buddy this link works